# Java Regex: Meaning of expression

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to figure out meaning of this regular expression:

```
.{0,70}(?:\\S(?:-| |$)|$)
```

I understood the meaning of this expression using [regexper](http://www.regexper.com/#.%7B0,70%7D%28?%3a%5C%5CS%28?%3a-%7C%20%7C%24%29%7C%24%29).

What I understood:

1) 1 to 70 characters except new line

2) then there can be end of line (at the end of the expression we have "|$)") OR

3) in non capturing group second alternative is "\S(?:-| |$)". It says it can not be non-whitespace characters "-" or SPACE or "end os line".

My understanding might be incorrect. I am not able to find out how does it work. Can you please explain me with some test data examples?

Comment: Have you tried looking at a table of regex symbols? Or have you understood parts of it? Be more clear about what's causing the confusion.

Comment: Where did you get it from ?

Comment: Sorry, SO is not place where we will write tutorial for you. There are many great ones already, like [this one](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). Voting to put your question on hold until you specify which part exactly confuses you.

Comment: I have updated my question with my current understanding. It will be helpful, if you could mention some examples on how does it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can ignore the fact the groups are non-caputuring, because that has no influence on whether something matches, so we have:

```
.{0,70}(\\S(-| |$)|$)
```

`.{0,70}` 0-70 non new-line characters

Followed by either (surrounded in single quotes so the space is visible):

- `'\S-'` a non-whitespace character and a `-`
- `'\S '` a non-whitespace character and a space
- `'\S$'` a non-whitespace character and end of input
- `'$'` end of input

So I would say, it's trying to match any sets of up to 70 chars that are separated by either a `-` or a space.

I'm not sure what sort of input you would use this with.. Potentially something that takes a passage of text and splits it into lines no longer than 72 characters (with the final character being a space between words or a `-` in a hyphenated word)?

For the sake of an example if you reduce the `.{0,70}` to `.{0,10)`, the you could use it on the following input:

```
"Hello how are you? My name is Dr Bob Scott-Thomas"
```

To split it into:

```
           |<-10 limit here
"Hello how "
"are you? "|
"My name is "
"Dr Bob "  |
"Scott-"   |
"Thomas"   |
```

[RegExr Example](http://regexr.com?37bp9)

Comment: Thanks for the simple and clear example. It helped me to understand its meaning perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

A step by step explanation

- `.{0,70}` repeat "`.`" 0 or 1 or 2... up to 70 times ("`.`" = Any character)
- `(?:...)` Non capturing group (don't capture the string)
- `\\S` is "\S" (\S is a "A non-whitespace character")
- `(?:...)` second non capturing group
- `-| |$` "`-`" or " " (space) or `$` (`$` = the end of a line)
- `|$` or the end of a line

For more informations about java regex [see docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: Just to clarify: `.` = Any _one_ symbol. `\s` matches whitespace (spaces, tabs and newlines). `\S` is a negated `\s`
.

Comment: Just to add . can also = spaces and in some cases new lines as well.

Comment: I realise the does give a breakdown of the expression, but I struggle to believe it will give the OP any more insight into what the expression actually does than he already has.

Answer (score 0):

I just plugged it into regex101 and this is what it says:

```
. 0 to 70 times [greedy] Any character (except newline)
(?:\S(?:-| |$)|$) Non-capturing Group
1st Alternative: \S(?:-| |$)
  \S Any char except whitespaces [^\t \r\n\f\v]
  (?:-| |$) Non-capturing Group
  1st Alternative: -
    Literal -
  2nd Alternative:  
    Space (ASCII 32)
  3rd Alternative: $
    $ End of string
2nd Alternative: $
  $ End of string
```